# Textbox is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

I have to fix some thing on the UI

[image: UI]

The application is running perfectly fine 
But when i change the size of the groupboxsize, It gives me an error.

1. The variable 'txtHeureMinutes' is either undeclared or was never
   assigned.
2. The variable 'txtHeureHeure' is either undeclared or was
   never assigned

Here is a code

```
public class NumericalTextBox : TextBox
{
    private int MaxValue;

    public NumericalTextBox(int max_value = -1)
    {
        MaxValue = max_value;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}

partial class TestClass
{
    // some code
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();        

        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.txtHeureMinutes = new MyComp.Common.Controls.NumericalTextBox(60);
        this.txtHeureHeure = new MyComp.Common.Controls.NumericalTextBox(24);

        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);

        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtHeureMinutes);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtHeureHeure);
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(270, 270);
    }

    // declaration
    private MyComp.Common.Controls.NumericalTextBox txtHeureMinutes;
    private MyComp.Common.Controls.NumericalTextBox txtHeureHeure;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it is not an Error. It's a 'WARNING' only.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg : i guess now you can reply to my question

Comment: @ChandanRoy : no its an error. plz check the attached Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the `designer.cs` file to confirm that the textboxes are indeed present in the collection of form controls.

Comment: There's no requirement that *fields* be declared before any *method* that accesses those fields.

Comment: Is that so? I wasn't aware of that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @shree.pat18 : Yes it is present i have added some images.